# Extraer datos Excel para incluirlos en BBDD Sql Server

Tags: python, sql-server, excel

Estoy realizando un desarrollo en Python que consiste básicamente en extraer datos de archivos en Excel (.xlsx) para incluirlos en tablas en SQL Server, estas son las condiciones:

1. Inicialmente son 5 usuarios que iran incrementando en el tiempo
2. Cada usuario tendrá un archivo en excel de 22 columnas y filas variables
3. Todos los usuarios depositarán el excel en una ruta fija, la misma para todos, el nombre de cada archivo tendrá la estructura DCR_XX, donde XX será un código de 2 dígitos único para cada usuario
4. El desarrollo debe tomar cada archivo excel e incluir la información en una tabla diferente en una BBDD llamada db_dcr, pero 
   el nombre de la tabla es fijo para cada usuario
5. Los nombres de las tablas serán iguales al nombre del archivo excel
6. La primera vez que el usuario cargue un excel se debe crear la tabla y los encabezados deben ser los mismos del excel y guardar los datos del excel en la tabla
7. Posteriormente cuando un usuario cargue un excel (semanalmente) se debe borrar el contenido de la tabla correspondiente y cargar todos los datos

He usado pandas para capturar los datos de cada excel el problema o consulta es como crear las tablas para la primera vez que el usuario cargue el excel y como transferir los datos del excel que estan capturados en un data frame a cada tabla, no tengo problemas en crear las conexiones a SQL Server el problema es la inserción de datos a las tablas

Comment: La pregunta que realizas es un poco ambigua ya que indicas los pasos de tu desarrollo, pero no la duda o dificultad especifica que presentas, te recomiendo leer ¿Como elaboro una buena pregunta? en https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

> el problema o consulta es como crear las tablas para la primera vez.

La solución a esto es preguntar cada vez, si las tablas existen, y si no existen crearlas.

```
if (OBJECT_ID('dbo.laTabla','U'))IS NULL
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE laTabla (id int);
END
```

La definición de la tabla, ya la tienes que tener fijada, por tanto una vez creado, solo tienes que hacer el insert correspondiente.

Como ejemplo
[Insert Sql server desde php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498692/insert-php-sql-server)

Comment: El tema de la validación de la existencia de la tabla lo pude resolver estandarizando los encabezados de cada archivo que usan los usuarios, pero el problema que aun tengo es al momento de tratar de insertar los datos en cada tabla